# How to convert images with negative number as a name to animation/video?

Tags: bash, sorting, locale, imagemagick-convert, basename

I create [animation ( gif)](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A600_100.gif) or video from a sequence of static images. Images have real number as a name, for example -1.000.pgm

When numbers are positive ( without minus sign) then it works

```
    #!/bin/bash 
 
# script file for BASH 
# which bash
# save this file as e.sh
# chmod +x e.sh
# ./e.sh
# checked in https://www.shellcheck.net/




printf "make pgm files \n"
gcc e.c -lm -Wall -march=native -fopenmp

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo ERROR: compilation failed !!!!!!
    exit 1
fi


export  OMP_DISPLAY_ENV="TRUE"
printf "display OMP info \n"

printf "run the compiled program\n"
time ./a.out > e.txt

export  OMP_DISPLAY_ENV="FALSE"

printf "change Image Magic settings\n"
export MAGICK_WIDTH_LIMIT=100MP
export MAGICK_HEIGHT_LIMIT=100MP

printf "convert all pgm files to png using Image Magic v 6 convert \n"

for file in *.pgm ; do
  # b is name of file without extension
  b=$(basename ./$file .pgm)
  # convert from pgm to gif and add text ( level ) using ImageMagic
  # https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html
  convert $file -pointsize 50 -annotate +10+100 ${b:0:4} ${b}.gif
  echo $file
 
done
 
# convert gif files to animated gif
convert *.gif -resize 600x600 a600_100.gif


printf "delete all pgm files \n"
rm ./*.pgm

 
echo OK
```

but when number is negative then the order in gif is wrong.
I have tried chang e name to positive integers :

```
i=0
for file in *.pgm ; do
  # b is name of file without extension
  b=$(basename ./$file .pgm)
  # convert from pgm to gif and add text ( level ) using ImageMagic
  # https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html
  convert $file -pointsize 50 -annotate +10+100 ${b:0:4} ${i}.gif
  echo $file
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

without good result.

How can I do it ?

============= edit 1===================

The result after Maxxim's answers :

[image]

I think that alphabetic sorting is also inside for loop, so it should be changed there also

=============== edit 2 ========================

```
printf '%s\n' *.gif | sort -n
-1.000000.gif
0.000000.gif
-0.200000.gif
0.200000.gif
-0.400000.gif
0.400000.gif
-0.600000.gif
0.600000.gif
-0.800000.gif
0.800000.gif
a200.gif
1.000000.gif

locale
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: The sorting within the `for` loop doesn't matter as it only converts all `.pgm` files to `.gif` files (thus the order doesn't matter as long as all files are processed). How do you get files with negative numbers in the first place? I ran `e.sh` and `e.c` myself and I don't get any files with negative numbers.

Comment: @Maxxim In main function from e.c change double t0 = 0.0 ;  to t0=-1 or -2

Comment: With `double t0 = -1.0`, I had to change line `b=$(basename $file .pgm)` to `b=$(basename -- $file .pgm)` due to errors and do the conversion to animated gif like described in my answer. With that, I get an `a600_100.gif` that plays perfectly. If that doesn't work for you, could you please upload the output of `printf '%s\n' *.gif | sort -n` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69695574/is-it-possibly-to-sort-files-numerically-when-nemas-arre-real-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a matter of sorting. You currently use `*.gif`, which is expanded into an [alphabetically](https://serverfault.com/a/122743/580326) sorted list of files. But you need a *numerically* sorted list of files here instead to achieve your goal. Additionally, your locale settings affect sorting (see `man sort`).

Try this:

```
readarray -t files < <(printf '%s\n' *.gif | LC_ALL=C sort -n)
convert "${files[@]}" -resize 600x600 a600_100.gif
```

or this:

```
readarray -t files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.gif' -printf "%f\n" | LC_ALL=C sort -n)
convert "${files[@]}" -resize 600x600 a600_100.gif
```

instead of:

```
convert *.gif -resize 600x600 a600_100.gif
```

Comment: what works for me : readarray -t files < <(printf '%s\n' *.gif | LC_ALL=C sort -n)
convert "${files[@]}" -resize 600x600 a600.gif

Comment: @Adam: yes, I also discovered the same thing a minute ago. So the issue is sorting + locale. I'll update my answer later.

Comment: @Adam: I extended my answer to include the part regarding locale settings.