# Is it possibly to sort files numerically when names are real numbers?

Tags: bash, filenames, ls

I have a files which names are real numbers, both positive and negative.
I need numerical order of files, like -1.0, -0.5,0.0, 0.5, 1.0 .... to make [animation from the files](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A600_100.gif)

I have tried

```
ls -v1 -- *.pgm
```

but the result is

```
0.000000.pgm
0.080000.pgm
0.160000.pgm
0.240000.pgm
0.320000.pgm
0.400000.pgm
0.480000.pgm
0.560000.pgm
0.640000.pgm
0.720000.pgm
0.800000.pgm
0.880000.pgm
0.960000.pgm
1.040000.pgm
1.120000.pgm
1.200000.pgm
1.280000.pgm
1.360000.pgm
1.440000.pgm
1.520000.pgm
1.600000.pgm
1.680000.pgm
1.760000.pgm
1.840000.pgm
1.920000.pgm
2.000000.pgm
-0.080000.pgm
-0.160000.pgm
-0.240000.pgm
-0.320000.pgm
-0.400000.pgm
-0.480000.pgm
-0.560000.pgm
-0.640000.pgm
-0.720000.pgm
-0.800000.pgm
-0.880000.pgm
-0.960000.pgm
-1.040000.pgm
-1.120000.pgm
-1.200000.pgm
-1.280000.pgm
-1.360000.pgm
-1.440000.pgm
-1.520000.pgm
-1.600000.pgm
-1.680000.pgm
-1.760000.pgm
-1.840000.pgm
-1.920000.pgm
-2.000000.pgm
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `ls | sort -n`? Not my downvote, btw.

Comment: @James Brown:  -2.000000.pgm -1.040000.pgm -1.120000.pgm ... not realy the solution

Comment: What's your locale, does it use a comma as a decimal separator? In that case, use for example: `ls | LC_ALL=C sort -n`

Comment: @JamesBrown Can I use this as an input for image magic convert ?

Comment: How did you feed the output of `ls` to the program? Update that to the question.

Comment: readarray -t files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.gif' -printf "%f\n" | sort -n)
convert "${files[@]}" -resize 200x200 a200.gif

Comment: Wild guess: add the `LC_ALL=C` before the `sort -n`: `... | LC_ALL=C sort -n)...` Sorry, I'm about out of time here, good luck, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `sort -g` "general numeric sort"

```sh
mapfile -t sorted_files < <(printf '%s\n' *.pgm | sort -g)
declare -p sorted_files
```